# Gnuplot: plotting x,y and z values on splot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have a data file like this:

> ```
>       1   10.0000000       10.0000000      -9.09194946E-02   8.99090767       8.09190845    
>       2  -9.09194946E-02   8.99090767      -1.09034777E-03  -1.18255615E-04   1.19025674E-06
>       3  -1.09034777E-03  -1.18255615E-04   9.30158421E-08  -9.31965042E-06   8.69424064E-12
>       4   9.30158421E-08  -9.31965042E-06  -2.51461074E-11  -8.18545232E-12   6.39026861E-22
> ```

I need to plot (using splot) this combinations:

2° column as x, 3° column as y, 5° column as z

4° column as x, 5° column as y, 5° column as z

How can I achieve this? Indeed some points are going to overwrite graphically but that's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I need to plot (using splot) this combinations:

2° column as x, 3° column as y, 5° column as z

```
  splot 'data' using 2:3:5 with points
```

4° column as x, 5° column as y, 5° column as z

```
  splot 'data' using 4:5:5 with points
```